# How to retrieve exact computed width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to get the equivalent of `getComputedStyle` for width through the jQuery api?  I want the fractional float values that are in the computed values but `width()` and `css()` both give me integers.  I have a fiddle here that shows the difference in values I'm getting.

http://jsfiddle.net/dchesterman/6Lyohk2d/1/

From what I can tell in the source, the issue is that `css.getWidthOrHeight` defaults to the offset before checking any computed values and I can't find a code path that lets me use the value from `getComputedValue`.

Comment: Why not use `getComputedStyle`?

Comment: Fair question.  I suppose I would like the `getComputedValue` value when safe but its not necessarily from what I know across browsers or properties.  Along with that, I'm curious why its not used.  It seems more accurate but people who know more than I wrote it to not use that and I'm wondering why.

Comment: `getComputedStyle` works very well, so long as it exists. Check the browsers you intend to support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle